# How to send data from server to client using AJAX?

Tags: ajax, node.js, rest, coffeescript

I want to query MongoDB and retrieve some documents. Then stream those documents back to the client to populate a `<table>` without refreshing the page. I already know how to do this using socket.io, but I want to learn how to transfer data without sockets. I am currently getting a `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)` because I do not have a `/loadRecent` resource, but I do not know how to perform a `GET` without loading a new page. (I might be missing some basic knowledge on how REST works.) Please advice.

Server code:

```
#Get recent documents
            app.get '/loadRecent', (req, res) ->
                console.log 'Documents requested...'
                db.collection 'documents', (err, collection) ->
                    collection.find().sort(dateAdded:-1) (err, cursor) ->
                        if not err
                            res.setHeader 'content-type':'application/json'
                            cursor.each (err, item) ->
                                res.write item
                        else
                            console.log 'Error getting recent docs: ' + err
```

Client code (Right now there is only a `console.log`, but the plan is to append data to `<table>` once I get the data flowing through.):

```
$.getJSON('/loadRecent', function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
            {
                console.log('Data recieved from server: ' + data);
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try building the JSON in the for each of the cursor instead of trying to write every time.

Build the JSON, then use res.send when the cursor is NULL so you know its done building it.